# Automate Data Feeds challenges

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, oracle-sqldeveloper, informatica-powercenter

I get monthly data feeds from source that i need to import into database but the problem is that the feed changes every month, sometimes there are more columns and  sometimes there are less columns. There is no consistency whatsoever.

How do I manage and automate these data feeds?

Comment: So what technology are you really using here? You have Informatica, SSIS and Oracle SQL Developer tagged

Comment: Earlier i was trying to see if i can handle this successfully in any BI tools.. but SSIS is good.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than expertise and out of box thinking, I think this needs a forthright response that automation is impossible unless the data provider commits to a particular column structure.

Comment: at least how to handle variable column count as a start in SSIS.

Comment: Very difficult, if possible at all.  SSIS is based on the idea that column structure is set up at design time, and doesn't change at run-time.  Somehow getting your data into a table, and then using dynamic SQL querying the table's column-structure to build the required statement, would be more likely to work.

Comment: Since there is no easy way out, these are steps i want to take                                                                                    1. Find out how many columns are there in the file.                                2. Additional columns will be executed based on step#1.                        3. Do the Bulk insert all steps are going to be done in the script task using SSIS.                                                                                                                I want to know if this is feasible to do.

Comment: Or you could try BIML: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/

Comment: at best that might automate creating a package according to whichever column structure happens to be current in a particular month.